# Replacing bulb in outdoor light fixture

Tags: lighting

[image]I have changed this bulb in the past, and know that I must unscrew finial at bottom of light fixture, but it absolutely will not unscrew for me. I’ve used pliers, a wrench, my strong husband. We live in a very windy, dusty environment. Any suggestions on how to loosen this finial?
Thank you!!

Comment: How about a picture or two so we can see what you see.  We have no idea what the problem is or how to fix it.

Comment: BTW, I've seen similar fixtures where the glass panels slide up, but you're sure about the finial unscrewing.

Comment: Because its upside down, perhaps you are turning it the wrong way.

Comment: Based on the offset of the parts, my guess would be that you got water in the bottom there which has caused corrosion in the fastener.

Answer (score 1):

Try heating the part (limiting heating to the part as much as possible.) That may help to loosen the hold corrosion presumably has on it, and should expand its threads away from the nipple it's screwed on to. You can also try a penetrating oil *such as Kroil, PB-Blaster, Liquid Wrench or a mixture of automatic transmission fluid and xylene.* But I'd suggest heating it first.

When you get it apart, apply some anti-seize compound (preferred) or grease (likely to be handier if you don't have anti-seize already) before reassembling.